# Id de la tabla usuarios a partir del logueo

Tags: php, mysqli, login

Tabla usuarios: iduser, nombre, usuario, contraseña, grupo
En el logueo debe introducir usuario, contraseña y grupo

```
<?php
include('00_conn.php');
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM $t98 WHERE (98_username= '$usuario' AND 98_clave = '$clave' AND '98_grupo = '$grupo')";
$respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

if( $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($respuesta) ) fila
{
   if (password_verify($clave,$fila)) {
        session_start();  //habilita uso de sesiones
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['grupo'] = $grupo; 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;   }
}
?>
```

Concretamente: como puedo obtener el Iduser y llevarmelo como variable  para incrustarlo en cada intervención que tenga en la carga de la bbdd
Espero haber sido clara!
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y no corresponde, pero señora mayor, somos todos gente grande por aquí ;)

Comment: y no puedes guardar el id de usuario como variable de sesion?

Comment: tan sencillo como guardar el valor que tiene iduser luego que el fetch array lo asignaste a la variable $file dentro de una variable de session y listo. no se entiende mucho el codigo, esta raro, pero ahi tenes la consulta a la base de datos y deberias traerte el campo iduser y meterlo en la session y deberias tener lo que queres

Comment: Sé, que el código que puse no llega a 'porqueria',  lo puedo corregir, deambulando por las páginas, encontré varios mucho mejores, no me preocupa por ahora.
Por muchos años hace algunas décadas  trabajé bastante con bbdd y mysql, pero ahora ya 'jubilada' me salió una 'changuita' y me vendría bien esa $variable
Pasé de hacer catálogos digitales de 500.000 renglones a una cosa muy simple que requiere, 'eso', llevar un numero de iduser y poderlo estampar,  donde quiera, pero no se como hacerlo
y COMO ES TAN SIMPLE, no aparece.
Agradecería ¿ 'donde recojo el id' ? y como me lo llevo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa esto a ver si te funciona, en donde estan las variables de $_SESSION pones las que quieres tomar para manejar en el sistema, ademas que estas repitiendo username 2 veces...

```js
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM elnombredetutabla WHERE 98_username='$usuario' and 98_clave='$clave'";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
 if(isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['clave'])){
 {
  if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
  {
   if($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
   { 
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['iduser'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['grupo'] = $grupo; 
    
    header('Location: ./lapaginaquequieresmostrar.php');
   }
  }
  else
  {
   echo '<script> alert("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos."); </script>';
  }
```

Comment: Hola Anderson, muchas gracias, si no entendí mal una vez que obtengo la variable $row (que contiene todos los datos que coinciden con el logueado) ahí puedo establecer la variable $idusr y llevarmela por post a cuestas mientras dure la session.
Si es así Gracias y cerramos aquí ya abriré otras preguntas como para quemar los jóvenes cerebros (si me da el cuero)
Estado actual PROBANDO

Answer (score 1):

Esto hasta aquí funciona como perfecto, divino, me manda donde pido y todo!!!!
así que aquí CERRAMOS (no se como se hace) y se viene en la próxima novela..
a) como recuperar el idusr en otra pagina
b) como llevar al usuario al menú correspondiente según su grupo (supongo que con case y switch y todo eso. 
Por ahora... gracias y me voy con una ligera inclinacion de cabeza y torso agradeciendo las repuestas brindadas!

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
require('00_0encab.inc');
require('00_1menu_usuar.inc');
include('/Connections/00_conn.php');
$username= $_POST['username'];
$clave= $_POST['clave'];
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM $t98 WHERE 98_username='$username' and 98_clave='$clave'";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['clave'])){
    {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
        {
            if($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
            { 
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['98_idusr'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['clave'] = $clave; 


                header('Location: Index_adm.php');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<script> alert("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos."); </script>';
        }   
    }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Amiga silvana la metodología del sitio Stack Overflow es darle en respuesta cuando sea una, no cuando sea una duda

Comment: Pudieras colocar el código html el cual estas trabajando en la pagina que quieres que se tome el iduser porfa

Comment: por cierto modificalo en el codigo  $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['clave'] = $row['clave'];

Comment: creo que tu duda es inclinada a lo que se llama permisos de los usuarios, a ver, ¿Lo que quieres hacer es que depende de la persona que inicie sesión se le muestre algunas cosas del menú?

Comment: Así es Anderson, pero creo que en esta instancia fui bastante clara, el código que subí funciona a efectos del logueo que era mi pregunta inicial. 
Respecto  de a) y b) estoy estudiando y verificando a efecto de saber antes de hacer la pregunta si es que necesito hacerla. Nuevamente muchas gracias!

Comment: Ok cualquier duda preguntas

Comment: gracias! Así lo haré